# No iAd's showing after 1 weeks time in version 2 app

Tags: ios, iad, appstore-approval

One week ago I had version 2 of my app approved and released to AppStore. No iAd's were showing then, and they haven't come since. A lot of rather old posts have users saying that they usually appear rather suddenly, and after about 3-4 days time. So do people on here have some up to date experience with this?

Also I'm thinking it could be that no advertisers have content that suits my app, but in that case: is there anyone who holds information about what happens in that case - i.e. do you get a message from Apple?

Additional: The app is strictly danish - where iAd has been up running for a long time. I have  contacted apple support, only to get the answer that I needed to implement iAd into my app(which of course I had done!) and was then referred to another division from which I haven't heard back after now most of a weeks time.

Comment: Have you added iAd.framework in your project..?

Comment: Yes, everything was running fine in simulator and on iPad with test ads

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with iAd banners in an app.  Although I had followed all of the programming steps to show iAds in my app, and they showed properly in the simulator, I hadn't enabled them in iTunes Connect before uploading my app.

Instructions for this are [in Apple's developer guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/ConfiguringStoreTechnologies.html).

Comment: Hmm, that would indeed make a lot of sense! I just checked it, without finding anything. Then found this one - check the answer with the image:
stackoverflow.com/questions/23569747/set-up-iad-network-button-doesnt-appear-on-itunesconnect

Comment: The button should show up when you go to manage the app.  There's a guide with images at http://www.appsvolcano.com/index.php/support/how-to-make-own-mobile-apps-for-iphone-android-kindle-ipad?catid=4&faqid=51 that might help.

Comment: Seems to me like that thread I just linked to is right - that button isn't showing for me. And I think that makes sense, when they put it directly that it's no longer necessary to enable it for each app